# ffmpeg hangs when trying to convert analog static from fpv drone

Tags: ffmpeg, python, video-editing

I am trying to convert a .MOV file to an .mp4 file using moviepy, which as I understand is a wrapper for ffmpeg. I have had prior success, but was disappointed when ffmpeg ground to a halt at 89%. I left it for over an hour but no progress was made. I was curious if there was something in the video that was causing the issue. Turns out that there is analog static at the end.

I am very confident this is the issue, as I used some other software to trim out the analog static and ffmpeg managed it just fine. However, I attempting to automate extracting scenes from my videos with time stamps and having ffmpeg grind to a halt without any errors doesn't help!

I have included the log file as well if that is worth anything!

```
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 497166 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 720x480, 497166 kb/s, 59.94 tbr, 59.94 tbn, 59.94 tbc
Input #1, mp3, from 'convertedTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:07:33.80, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
[libx264 @ 000001aea287cd80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001aea287cd80] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001aea287cd80] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'converted.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480, q=-1--1, 59.94 fps, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54
[rawvideo @ 000001aea287c400] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
frame=  111 fps=0.0 q=31.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:00.88 bitrate=4717.2kbits/s speed=1.74x    
frame=  196 fps=194 q=31.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:02.29 bitrate=5471.4kbits/s speed=2.27x    
frame=  276 fps=182 q=31.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:03.62 bitrate=5792.8kbits/s speed=2.39x    
frame=  368 fps=182 q=31.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:05.15 bitrate=5695.3kbits/s speed=2.56x    
frame=  451 fps=179 q=31.0 size=    4352kB time=00:00:06.55 bitrate=5436.6kbits/s speed=2.61x    
frame=  534 fps=177 q=31.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:07.94 bitrate=5545.1kbits/s speed=2.63x    
frame=  628 fps=178 q=31.0 size=    5888kB time=00:00:09.50 bitrate=5072.2kbits/s speed= 2.7x    
frame=  725 fps=180 q=31.0 size=    6656kB time=00:00:11.12 bitrate=4899.4kbits/s speed=2.77x    
frame=  817 fps=181 q=31.0 size=    7168kB time=00:00:12.67 bitrate=4634.5kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=  910 fps=181 q=31.0 size=    7936kB time=00:00:14.21 bitrate=4574.6kbits/s speed=2.83x    
frame=  987 fps=179 q=31.0 size=    8704kB time=00:00:15.49 bitrate=4602.7kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame= 1076 fps=179 q=31.0 size=    9728kB time=00:00:16.96 bitrate=4696.9kbits/s speed=2.82x    
frame= 1159 fps=177 q=31.0 size=   10496kB time=00:00:18.36 bitrate=4681.9kbits/s speed=2.81x    
frame= 1240 fps=176 q=31.0 size=   11520kB time=00:00:19.72 bitrate=4784.8kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame= 1323 fps=175 q=31.0 size=   12544kB time=00:00:21.10 bitrate=4868.3kbits/s speed=2.79x    
frame= 1411 fps=175 q=31.0 size=   13312kB time=00:00:22.55 bitrate=4834.7kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame= 1495 fps=174 q=31.0 size=   14336kB time=00:00:23.98 bitrate=4897.2kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame= 1583 fps=175 q=31.0 size=   15104kB time=00:00:25.44 bitrate=4862.9kbits/s speed=2.81x    
frame= 1682 fps=176 q=31.0 size=   15872kB time=00:00:27.07 bitrate=4802.0kbits/s speed=2.83x    
frame= 1777 fps=176 q=31.0 size=   16640kB time=00:00:28.68 bitrate=4752.4kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame= 1862 fps=176 q=31.0 size=   17408kB time=00:00:30.08 bitrate=4740.9kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame= 1943 fps=175 q=31.0 size=   18432kB time=00:00:31.45 bitrate=4800.7kbits/s speed=2.83x      
...
frame=19626 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  191488kB time=00:05:26.45 bitrate=4805.2kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=19721 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  192000kB time=00:05:28.02 bitrate=4794.9kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=19812 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  192768kB time=00:05:29.56 bitrate=4791.7kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=19901 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  193280kB time=00:05:31.05 bitrate=4782.8kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=19994 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  194048kB time=00:05:32.59 bitrate=4779.6kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=20083 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  194816kB time=00:05:34.06 bitrate=4777.3kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=20164 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  195584kB time=00:05:35.43 bitrate=4776.5kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=20252 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  196352kB time=00:05:36.88 bitrate=4774.6kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=20340 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  197120kB time=00:05:38.35 bitrate=4772.5kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=20427 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  197888kB time=00:05:39.82 bitrate=4770.4kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=20509 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  198656kB time=00:05:41.18 bitrate=4769.8kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=20579 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  199680kB time=00:05:42.36 bitrate=4777.9kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=20650 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  200448kB time=00:05:43.53 bitrate=4779.9kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=20728 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  201472kB time=00:05:44.84 bitrate=4786.1kbits/s speed=2.79x    
frame=20814 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  202240kB time=00:05:46.26 bitrate=4784.7kbits/s speed=2.79x    
frame=20892 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  202752kB time=00:05:47.58 bitrate=4778.5kbits/s speed=2.79x    
frame=20966 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  203520kB time=00:05:48.81 bitrate=4779.7kbits/s speed=2.79x    
frame=21035 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  204032kB time=00:05:49.95 bitrate=4776.2kbits/s speed=2.79x    
frame=21099 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  204288kB time=00:05:51.01 bitrate=4767.6kbits/s speed=2.79x    
frame=21158 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  204800kB time=00:05:52.02 bitrate=4765.9kbits/s speed=2.78x    
frame=21226 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  205312kB time=00:05:53.15 bitrate=4762.6kbits/s speed=2.78x    
frame=21290 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  205568kB time=00:05:54.22 bitrate=4754.1kbits/s speed=2.78x    
frame=21362 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  206336kB time=00:05:55.42 bitrate=4755.8kbits/s speed=2.78x    
frame=21428 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  207104kB time=00:05:56.52 bitrate=4758.8kbits/s speed=2.77x    
frame=21492 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  207616kB time=00:05:57.59 bitrate=4756.2kbits/s speed=2.77x    
frame=21553 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  208128kB time=00:05:58.61 bitrate=4754.4kbits/s speed=2.77x    
frame=21625 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  208640kB time=00:05:59.79 bitrate=4750.4kbits/s speed=2.77x    
frame=21694 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  209408kB time=00:06:00.94 bitrate=4752.7kbits/s speed=2.76x    
frame=21761 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  209920kB time=00:06:02.08 bitrate=4749.3kbits/s speed=2.76x    
frame=21835 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  210432kB time=00:06:03.31 bitrate=4744.8kbits/s speed=2.76x    
frame=21919 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  210944kB time=00:06:04.72 bitrate=4738.0kbits/s speed=2.76x    
frame=22006 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  211712kB time=00:06:06.15 bitrate=4736.6kbits/s speed=2.76x    
frame=22151 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  211968kB time=00:06:08.58 bitrate=4711.1kbits/s speed=2.77x    
frame=22297 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  212224kB time=00:06:11.01 bitrate=4685.9kbits/s speed=2.78x    
frame=22427 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  212736kB time=00:06:13.18 bitrate=4669.9kbits/s speed=2.78x    
frame=22565 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  212992kB time=00:06:15.48 bitrate=4646.9kbits/s speed=2.79x    
frame=22707 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  213248kB time=00:06:17.86 bitrate=4623.2kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=22848 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  213504kB time=00:06:20.19 bitrate=4600.3kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=22964 fps=169 q=31.0 size=  213760kB time=00:06:22.14 bitrate=4582.3kbits/s speed=2.81x    
frame=23094 fps=169 q=31.0 size=  214272kB time=00:06:24.30 bitrate=4567.6kbits/s speed=2.81x    
frame=23232 fps=169 q=31.0 size=  214528kB time=00:06:26.60 bitrate=4545.8kbits/s speed=2.82x    
frame=23351 fps=170 q=31.0 size=  214784kB time=00:06:28.59 bitrate=4527.8kbits/s speed=2.82x    
frame=23482 fps=170 q=31.0 size=  215040kB time=00:06:30.79 bitrate=4507.8kbits/s speed=2.83x    
frame=23617 fps=170 q=31.0 size=  215296kB time=00:06:33.02 bitrate=4487.5kbits/s speed=2.83x    
frame=23726 fps=170 q=31.0 size=  215808kB time=00:06:34.86 bitrate=4477.2kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame=23819 fps=171 q=31.0 size=  216576kB time=00:06:36.39 bitrate=4475.8kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame=23908 fps=171 q=31.0 size=  217600kB time=00:06:37.88 bitrate=4480.2kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame=24002 fps=171 q=31.0 size=  218368kB time=00:06:39.44 bitrate=4478.3kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame=24097 fps=171 q=31.0 size=  218880kB time=00:06:41.05 bitrate=4470.8kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame=24193 fps=171 q=31.0 size=  219648kB time=00:06:42.65 bitrate=4468.8kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame=24293 fps=171 q=31.0 size=  220160kB time=00:06:44.32 bitrate=4460.7kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame=24330 fps=170 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.84x    
frame=24330 fps=170 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.83x    
frame=24330 fps=169 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.82x    
frame=24330 fps=169 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.81x    
frame=24330 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed= 2.8x    
frame=24330 fps=168 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.79x    
frame=24330 fps=167 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.78x    
frame=24330 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.77x    
frame=24330 fps=166 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.76x    
frame=24330 fps=165 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.75x    
frame=24330 fps=165 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.74x    
frame=24330 fps=164 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.73x    
frame=24330 fps=164 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.72x    
frame=24330 fps=163 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.71x    
frame=24330 fps=162 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed= 2.7x    
frame=24330 fps=162 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.69x    
frame=24330 fps=161 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.68x    
frame=24330 fps=161 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.68x    
frame=24330 fps=160 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.67x    
frame=24330 fps=160 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.66x    
frame=24330 fps=159 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.65x    
frame=24330 fps=159 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.64x    
frame=24330 fps=158 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.63x    
frame=24330 fps=158 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.62x    
frame=24330 fps=157 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.61x    
frame=24330 fps=157 q=31.0 size=  221696kB time=00:06:44.92 bitrate=4485.1kbits/s speed=2.61x
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally had some time to revisit this after a busy week.

Turns out its not to do with the analog static specifically. Or maybe only partly. I was able to convert another video that had static in it just fine. This tipped me off that there is just some unique corruption in the video.

I was able to convert using shotcut just, fine, then I tried stock ffmpeg. Stock ffmpeg showed a lot of errors but was will able to complete the process and the video at the end looked great. I don't know what pymovie is doing, but I like working with ffmpeg directly however.

Fun fact though, I used ChatGPT 3.5 to quickly work out out the ffmpeg commands and develop a script using the `subprocess` command to run ffmpeg. Its trivial and I could have looked it up but I gave it shot with ChatGPT 3.5 and it worked. Eventually I learned about `subprocess.check_decode()` to monitor the output and now I have a script that I think is very robust. I even went as far as using hardware acceleration to process the video on my GPU. I also realized I didn't need to convert the video seemingly. I was able to directly extract the clips that I desired based on time. Pretty happy with the results!

````
import time
start_time = '2:33'
end_time = '2:51'


input_video = "video.MOV"
output_video = "output.mp4"

#Standard video conversion
ffmpeg_cmd = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-i', input_video,
    '-c:v', 'h264_nvenc',
    '-c:a', 'aac',
    'output.mp4', '-y', '']

#Extracting clip
ffmpeg_cmd_getclip = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-i', input_video,
    '-ss', start_time,
    '-to', end_time,
    output_video,'-y']

#Extracting clip with GPU
ffmpeg_cmd_getclipGPU =  [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-hwaccel', 'cuvid',
    '-c:v', 'h264_cuvid',
    '-i', input_video,
    '-ss', start_time,
    '-to', end_time,
    '-c:v', 'h264_nvenc',
    output_video, '-y']


print('Starting!')

start = time.time()
output = subprocess.check_output(ffmpeg_cmd_getclip)
output = output.decode()
end = time.time()
run1 = end - start
start = time.time()
output = subprocess.check_output(ffmpeg_cmd_getclipGPU)
output = output.decode()
end = time.time()
run2 = end - start
#Seems as if the outut decoding runs a little while after the process has completed. Small delay to make sure things are cleaned up.
time.sleep(2)
print('Completed!')
print(run1, run2)```
````